# How can I change the position of auto-generated windows with Phonegap?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using Phonegap (Cordova for iOS) with XCode and I'm using the Camera API to provide a window which enables the user to navigate through the image gallery and choose an image which then gets displayed on the moodboard.

Now I have this button which launches the window, but it is placed centered on the top with the "bubble arrow thing" on the left. I want to change the position of this window, and if possible move this arrow - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as of 1.8.0 release. We saw that folks were getting rejections from Apple since the arrow was pointed to the wrong spot so Becky fixed the issue. You can see the docs on it, [CameraPopoverOptions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#CameraPopoverOptions).

Comment: already tried that once but it didn't work because i was still working with cordova 1.7.0 - thanks for the tip! works like a charm after upgrading!